# How I can install the Epson TX 135?

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

How I can install? 
whenever I connect, it tells me not found the appropriate driver, any help is welcome, thanks.

---

¿Como puedo instalarlo?
Cada vez que conecto la impresora me dice que no encuentra el driver apropiado para esta.. en Fedora 15 me dice lo mismo... fue mi razon para cambiarme a Ubuntu.
Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Tem pra todos os Linuxers, Impressora e Escaner (Have to all Linuxers, printer and scanner) :
http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

Answer (score 1):

Baja el controlador del siguiente link (get the driver here)

http://global.latin.epson.com/Catalogo/Epson-Stylus-TX135/Soporte-Tecnico